# Pass parent pointer in derived constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, casting, polymorphism

So I was doing something like this:

```
    Base * pParentPtr

    // ... pParentPtr is used

    // Cast result pointer
    Derived* castedResult = (Derived*)pParentPtr;

    // Copy the referenced object to stack object
    Derived resultExplicitCopy = Derived(*castedResult);

    // run Derived class functions
    resultExplicitCopy.DeviredSpecialFunction();

    // Free memory allocated by factory
    delete pParentPtr;
```

Which means that the code uses `pParentPtr` but at the end we need it to be converted to `Derived`, then call a function that belongs only to `Derived` and then delete the initial pointer.

Although this works, the idea is to simplify the code. I thought on creating a contructor for `Derived` that takes a `Base*` for input:

```
Derived::Derived(Base* basePtr)
{
    // Cast result pointer
    Derived* castedResult = (Derived*)basePtr;

    // Copy the referenced object to stack object
    Derived resultExplicitCopy = Derived(*castedResult); // This looks bad

    // run Derived class functions
    resultExplicitCopy.DeviredSpecialFunction();

    *this = resultExplicitCopy; // ??? this seems weird and dangerous
}
```

Creating a `Derived` instance inside the constructor seems like a bad idea, also reseting the whole object before it actually exists.

So, is there a way of pasing `Base`'s pointer to `Derived`'s constructor and properly building it?

I'd like it to look like this:

```
    Base * pParentPtr

    // ... pParentPtr is used

    // Init derived with base
    derivedInstance = Derived(pParentPtr);


    // Free memory allocated by factory
    delete pParentPtr;
```

Comment: `Derived* castedResult = (Derived*)basePtr;` -- Warning -- this does a dangerous C-style cast, where there is no checking to see if `basePtr` is actually pointing to a `Derived`.

Comment: If `Derived` requires a `Derived` to be constructed from, why are you using a constructor with a `Base*` parameter? Shouldn't you be using the copy constructor with `const Derived&` parameter so that you can be sure that the parameter actually _does_ reference a `Derived`? (Although even then this might be a bad idea if `Derived` is not `final` because it would still be slicing. A virtual `clone` member function should make sure that the whole most-derived object is copied.)

Comment: *but at the end we need it to be converted to Derived* -- If the type is `Base`, there is no "conversion" that can be done.  It is a `Base`, period, full stop.  If you want a `Derived`, then you must create a `Derived`.  Faking out the type system by telling a fib that the `Base` is a `Derived` by doing a cast -- that isn't going to work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right, "convert" is not the right word, I need a `Derived` object that is a copy of a `Base` object

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie not sure if I *need* to cast , but I guess a dynamic cast should work

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this would be to take a Base* in the constructor function and then manually setting the data fields in the constructor so for example. This is because when you call a constructor it will 'return' an instantiated version of that object to your specifications:

```
field1=basePtr->field1
```

I would avoid using the cast because it is a dangerous C cast as what it is doing is saying instead of treating what this pointer points to as having a Base type treat the memory as if it had a Derived type and if the memory doesn't match up there could be problems

Answer (score 0):

This code is valid only if `pParentPtr` points to an object of class `Derived`. If it's true, then you can do one of these depending on the actual use case:

1. Directly call `castedResult->DeviredSpecialFunction()`.
2. If you don't like the `->` syntax for some reason (i'm assuming you're doing hobby project or it is not a peer-reviwed code, otherwise -> is perfectly fine), then you can "transform" pointer to a reference: `Derived& resultExplicitCopy = (Derived&)(*castedResult)` (note the two added ampersands).

Also I agree with comments noting that you should revise your design such that:

1. you don't blindly assume that `pParentPtr` points to `Derived`. Maybe the code above does the check already, but then still the following point holds:
2. you certainly shouldn't allow the construction of `Derived` form pointer `Base` if such construction blindly assumed that a pointer points to a `Derived`. Usually a class may be used in a different places in program, so a class's constructor should be clear in a way that you know what objects it may accept by looking at its signature. Having a proper parameter type makes it formally correct, and formal correctness actually makes things clearer. If constructor assumes its paremeter points to Derived, it should accept a `Derived*`, and accepting 'Base* `would be incorrect as it allows a pointer to a non-`Derived` object to be passed into it by mistake. In such a case the compiler can't help you by type checking.